# Unable to read file contents to string - Result does not implement any method in scope named `read_to_string`

Tags: error-handling, rust

I followed the code to open a file from [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/file/open.html):

```
use std::{env, fs::File, path::Path};

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let pattern = &args[1];

    if let Some(a) = env::args().nth(2) {
        let path = Path::new(&a);
        let mut file = File::open(&path);
        let mut s = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut s);
        println!("{:?}", s);
    } else {
        //do something
    }
}
```

However, I got a message like this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `read_to_string` found for type `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:14
   |
11 |         file.read_to_string(&mut s);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worth adding that the `?` operator is a succinct way of unwrapping or returning an error early now: let mut file = File::open(&path)? See [The ? operator for easier error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's look at your error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `read_to_string` found for type `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:14
   |
11 |         file.read_to_string(&mut s);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>`
```

The error message is pretty much what it says on the tin - the type [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) does **not** have the method `read_to_string`. That's actually [a method on the trait `Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string).

You have a `Result` because `File::open(&path)` can **fail**. Failure is represented with the `Result` type. A `Result` may be either an [`Ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Ok), which is the success case, or an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err), the failure case.

You need to handle the failure case somehow. The easiest is to just die on failure, using `expect`:

```
let mut file = File::open(&path).expect("Unable to open");
```

You'll also need to bring `Read` into scope to have access to `read_to_string`:

```
use std::io::Read;
```

I'd **highly recommend** reading through [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and working the examples. The chapter [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) will be highly relevant. I think these docs are top-notch!

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html: over here it does say that File has a read_to_string method. Why can't I access it here, as the first example code did?

Comment: @user3918985 `File` implements `Read`, which provides `read_to_string`. I don't what you mean by "here". You have to `use` that trait (as I show) to have those methods in scope.

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive explanation.

Comment: i just started learning rust too but the fact that you have to also import "Read" looks awful to me. The File object has already implemented the trait Read so shouldn't the exception tell me I have to import Read rather than plain saying I have a missing method?

Comment: @dtc [It **does** give you that suggestion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad0618baefad7b9345c880cafd08e93e): ``help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it: use std::io::Read;``. The problem is that **`Result`** doesn't have such a method, as described in the answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster woops, you're right. i rushed to conclusions but didn't read the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

If your method returns `Result<String, io::Error>`, you can use `?` on the functions that return a `Result`:

```rust
fn read_username_from_file() -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let mut f = File::open("hello.txt")?;
    let mut s = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
    Ok(s)
}
```

If you cannot return a `Result<String, io::Error>` then you have to handle error case using `expect` as mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29215624/155423) or matching on the `Result` and panicking:

```rust
let file = File::open(&opt_raw.config);

let file = match file {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(error) => {
        panic!("Problem opening the file: {:?}", error)
    }
};
```

For more information, please refer to [Recoverable Errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html).