# How to read in a fasta in Rust usio the bio package

Tags: rust, bioinformatics, rust-cargo

I'm pretty new to Rust (and bio rust) and just learning so any guidance would be appreciated. I've read the small Read Example for how to read in a fasta sequence from stdin,

```
let mut records = fasta::Reader::new(io::stdin()).records();
```

but I can't figure out how to read in from a file. I've tried

```
let mut records = fasta::Reader::new(filename);
```

Where the filename is a slice and a string and I've found the from_file function trying that as well. While some of them appear to work, then when I try to parse through them with for or while loops, they always complain that they're of the wrong type. The from_file function seems to not make an iterator, but a Result reader, so I can't call the next() or collect() function on it,

```
let mut records = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename);
let mut nb_reads = 0;
let mut nb_bases = 0;



while let Some(Ok(record)) = records.next() {
    nb_reads += 1;
    nb_bases += record.seq().len();


    let sa = suffix_array(record.seq());

    println!("Here's the Suffix array: {:#?}", sa);

    nb_reads += 1;
    nb_bases += record.seq().len();
}
```

while the for loop seems to work, but the 'result' iterator doesn't have the right type so I can't pull sequences.

```
let mut reader = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename);
let mut nb_reads = 0;
let mut nb_bases = 0;



for result in reader {
    nb_reads += 1;
    nb_bases += result.seq().len();


    let sa = suffix_array(result.seq());

    println!("Here's the Suffix array: {:#?}", sa);

    nb_reads += 1;
    nb_bases += result.seq().len();
}
```

I'm stumped, but I feel like I'm close to getting it to work. Thanks!

Comment: You need to check if `from_file` returned an error before you can use it. Easiest is to just `unwrap` it: `let mut reader = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename).unwrap();`

Comment: When I add unwrap to the original as well as in the for loop I get an error saying that it has been moved after the first call. I tried to call the reference with `&` but it doesn't work
`let reader = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename).unwrap();
    for result in reader.records() {
        nb_reads += 1;
        nb_bases += result.unwrap().seq().len();

    
        let sa = suffix_array(result.unwrap().seq());`Gives error here.
When I don't unwrap I can't call the `.seq()` function on them.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works, although I'm not sure if it's an answer

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename: &str = &args[1];

    
    let reader = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename).unwrap();
    let mut nb_reads = 0;
    let mut nb_bases = 0;


    
    for result in reader.records() {

        let result_data = &result.unwrap();

        nb_reads += 1;
        nb_bases += result_data.seq().len();

        println!("{:?}",result_data.id());

    }

    println!("Number of reads: {}", nb_reads);
    println!("Number of bases: {}", nb_bases);
}
```

It appears that you need to get the pointer of the unwrapped records in the fasta reader. I wish the documentation was a bit more helpful for beginners, but I'll leave this here for anyone else struggling. Also if you try to print the `.seq()` it may crash your terminal haha. Moral of the story is check your types and deal with Result types (I'll figure out how to properly unwrap them later, I know my code is far from optimal now)

Comment: You shouldn't need the dereference, but you can only `unwrap` a result once. So `let result_data = result.unwrap();` should work (without the `&`), but calling `result.unwrap()` more than once doesn't work.

Comment: This is because [`Result::unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) takes `self` by value and not by reference. Note that the docs say explicitly: _Returns the contained Ok value, **consuming the `self` value.**_

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the Result in order to get the type you expect.

For example:

`let reader = fasta::Reader::from_file(filename).expect("Unable to open");`

See this thread for more details:
[Unable to read file contents to string - Result does not implement any method in scope named `read_to_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214963/unable-to-read-file-contents-to-string-result-does-not-implement-any-method-in)