# No method named `write` found for enum `Result`

Tags: memory, rust, embedded

I'm trying to port a C program to Rust. In C I have this statement.

```c
bytes = write(filedevice, cmd, (ssize_t)LEN_SET_ADDRESS_AREA);
```

I tried to write it like this, but the compiler gives an error saying `` no method named `write` found for enum `Result` in the current scope `` . How can I fix this code without using unsafe Rust?

```rust
let path = Path::new(DEVICE);
let memory = vec![0; DIM_MEM];
let mut filedevice = File::create(_path);
let file_wr = fildevice.write(&_memory[0]);
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29214963/5397009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::fs::File::create()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) returns a `Result<File>`, so you have to do the error handling before accessing the inner `File` object.
A quick and dirty way is to call [`std::result::Result::unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) to unwrap the return value.

```rust
let mut file = File::create(path).unwrap();
file.write(buffer);
```

Note that this causes the program to panic if the `Result<File>` return value is an error. Read the [error handling chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) or the [module-level documentation for `std::result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/) for other ways to handle the error properly. Here are some examples:

**Using [`.expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect)**

This provides the ability to print customized error messages.

```rust
let mut file = File::create(path).expect("Failed to create file");
file.write(buffer);
```

**Using `match`**

As `Result<T, E>` is a enum type, we can use a `match` expression to perform pattern matching, and handle either cases in separate branches.

```rust
let mut file = match File::create(path) {
    Ok(file) => file,
    Err(error) => {
        // panic, or you may also want to handle it in other ways
        panic!("Problem creating file: {:?}", error);
    }
};
file.write(buffer);
```